# iOS - MPMoviePlayerController - load movie while playing

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to load video while the `MPMoviePlayerController` is already playing.

I have movie, and advertisement alternately, and i want to prevent from user the waiting while the player load the next URL.
I want to load an advertisement while the video is showing, and after 5 minutes I want the user will watch the advertisement immediately (without any loading delay).

For play the movie, I use the `prepareToPlay` method.

Does the framework support this? Or should I have to do it by my self (with `dispatch_async`)?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I'll do it async, using NSURLSession method :

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Nevertheless, don't forget you could not be 100% sure that your advertisement will be download in the next 5 minutes (network down, or download speed slow...).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to download the movie, can u think of something else?

Comment: Is your question : Is MPMoviePlayerController have several downloading cache ?

Comment: Ok, let's ask it this way, Does it have several downloading cache?